# Which API supports all network connections like Proxy(LAN), 3G, wifi and 4G for mac os x?

Tags: macos

Currently I am working MAC OS X application. I wanted to know whether my application is connected to LAN or Wi-Fi or 3G or 4G specifically.Currently I am using Apple Reachability classes to check Internet Connection.

When I gave App for beta release to client it's showing connected network as Wi-Fi not LAN and 4G even though application is connected to 4G network.

I want to find out Downloading speed, uploading speed and PING speed specifically. while connecting 4G --uploading speed not displaying in my application remaining all are showing perfectly. (If I use Wifi connection it's working perfectly) or (If I connected through LAN-- entire application is not working -- means results are not showing).

Comment: How does a Mac connect to the internet via 3G or 4G?  Some sort of tethering?

Comment: If network bandwidth (Downloading speed) has more than 30mbps or if i connected through LAN, i am unable to get the  speed of Downloading, uploading and PING. Don't think if it has 3g/4g, it is matter only in case of networking speed.

Comment: Your question makes no sense at all. Voting to close.